# Prove that $F$ mapping $V(\Omega\subset V)$ to $\partial \Omega$ can not be the identity mapping on $\partial\Omega$

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb R^n$ be compact and let $\partial\Omega$ be smooth. Let $V\subset\mathbb R^n$ be open and $\Omega\subset V$.Suppose  $int\Omega\neq\emptyset$. If $F\in C^1(V,\partial\Omega)$, can $F$ restricted to $\partial \Omega$  be the identity mapping?

I think the answer may be no and it may have something to do with stokes' theorem and Brouwer fixed point theorem,but   I can't give a proof.

Comment: This is an algebraic topology problem, see for example [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1836655/there-is-no-smooth-retraction-from-an-oriented-compact-manifold-to-its-boundary?rq=1).

Comment: What if $F=\operatorname{id}$?

Comment: @pem $F\in C^1(V,\partial\Omega)$

Comment: @Neal  I'm so sorry, but I can't see the connection between the two problems, can you explain it more specifically?

Comment: Such an $F$ when restricted to $\Omega$ would be a retraction of $\Omega$ to $\partial\Omega$.

Comment: For a concrete example, let $n=2$, let $\Omega$ be a closed ball of radius $1$, let $S^1 = \partial\Omega$ be its boundary, and let $V$ be an open ball of radius $1+\epsilon$. For any $F:V\to\partial\Omega$, $H = F|_\Omega$ is a nullhomotopy of $F|_{\partial\Omega}$ hence cannot be the identity map, which is nontrivial in $\pi_1(S^1)$.